# When I add an incrementing function it's not working?

Tags: c#

I am adding an Arithmetic operator to a simple program however it is not showing the correct answer when I run the program. I have tried adjusting my phrasing but have come to the conclusion that the incrementing operator is the problem. The "i++" has a little green line beneath it and that is where the problem lies.

```
using System;

namespace GotoSearch
{
    public class GotoSearch
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            int [] primes = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13};

            foreach (int prime in primes)
                Console.Write("{0} ", prime);
            
            Console.WriteLine();
            
            int target = 7;
            int i;

            for (i = 0; i < primes.Length; i++) 
            {
                if (target == primes[i])
                    Console.Write("{0} found at {1}", target, i);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} found at {1}", target, i);
                Console.ReadLine();
                return 0;

            }
            Console.Write("{0} not found", target);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} not found", target);
            Console.ReadLine();
            return 0;
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use "{}" at the `if` inside the `for`. That whole block needs to be conditional, not only one statement.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete error message you get and mark the line where the error is.

Comment: The green squigglies are there, because `i++` is never executed. You exit the loop unconditionally in the 1. iteration.

Comment: I am not getting an error message, when the console just says that 7 is found at 0 which is not true.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to replace

```
if (target == primes[i])
    Console.Write("{0} found at {1}", target, i);
Console.WriteLine("{0} found at {1}", target, i);
Console.ReadLine();
return 0;
```

with

```
if (target == primes[i])
{
    Console.Write("{0} found at {1}", target, i);
    Console.ReadLine();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank this fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

Inside this "block" of code:

```
if (target == primes[i])
    Console.Write("{0} found at {1}", target, i);
Console.WriteLine("{0} found at {1}", target, i);
Console.ReadLine();
return 0;
```

Is the intention to run all four lines below when the `if` statement is true?

If so, then you need BRACKETS:

```
if (target == primes[i])
{
    Console.Write("{0} found at {1}", target, i);
    Console.ReadLine();
    return 0;
}
```

Without those brackets, only the first line directly below runs when the `if` statement is true.

As written, the other three lines below are ALWAYS run (regardless of the result of the `if` statement), and the very first iteration of your `for` loop is going to hit `return 0` and STOP.

Get into the habit of always adding brackets for [if](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else) statements...even if that block includes only one line:

> Both the then-statement and the else-statement can consist of a single
> statement or multiple statements that are enclosed in braces ({}). For
> a single statement, the braces are optional but recommended.

Comment: "Get into the habit of always adding brackets for if statements" - also holds for "one-line `for`s"...